# How to applying percentage to price javascript?

Tags: javascript, percentage

```
percentage = 10%;
price = €50;
total = price + percent
```

How to apply  percentage to price? 
I tried to apply this

```
(percent / 100) +1 * price
```

but it is not correct in this case

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need [numbers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Number_type) and then calculate with these values the totel value.

The result could have some digits who are unwanted. In this case apply [Number#toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) for an output of a string with the wanted digits.

```js
var percent = 10,
    price = 50,
    total = price * (percent / 100 + 1);

document.write(total + '<br>');
document.write(total.toFixed(2));
```

Comment: u take proce as string, my solution takes price and percent as number without euro sign and percentage without percent sign.

Comment: My code is example :) i don't use the value as a string.. it was an example for explain well my problem.

Answer (score -1):

1% is 1/100 of initial value, I guess what you want to do is this:

```
(percent / 100) * price + price
```